# loading different function files in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have made 2 sets out of various functions in wordpress.

One set just effects the back-end or the admin-side and the other effects the front-end live site.

I want to load only the front-end functions file (`front-functions.php`) when the front site is browsed and load the back-end (`admin-functions.php`) file when the admin area is browsed.

Is it possible to do so? If yes, How?

Kindly help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try this code in your functions.php

```
if ( is_admin() ) {
     include_once('admin-functions.php')
} else {
     include_once('front-functions.php')
}
```

Regards,
jhOy